# Working of #define in C

Tags: c

I was going through my C learning by writing small pieces of code and one new question came up

I have written a small piece of code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define SUM(a) (a+a)
main()
{
  int w,b=5;
  w=SUM(b++);
  printf("%d\n",w);
  printf("%d\n",b);
  getch();     
}
```

What i was thinking that it will display the output as

10

6

but it is showing

10

7

Can someone explain why ,i am using Visual Studio 2008

Comment: I have no idea why are you using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: I have no idea why it is tagged `C++`

Comment: @2501 Correct would be "Can someone explain why?" "I am using Visual Studio 2008.", I don't see any `pause` there, so i assume that's what he wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because when you do

```
w=SUM(b++);
```

the macro will be replaced by:

```
w= b++ + b++;
```

now, if `b=5` then you do twice `b++` and get `b=7`

### Edit

after reading MSalters comment i did some searching and found out that as he said this code couse UB.

[as says here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP30-C.+Do+not+depend+on+the+order+of+evaluation+for+side+effects):

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either
>   a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value
>   computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is
>   undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the
>   subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an
>   unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.

Comment: Actually, you have Undefined Behavior and b = -42 is equally valid. Yo modify `b` twice without an intervening sequence point.

Comment: When you do `b++` twice you have an undefined behaviour.

Comment: @willys i've edit the answer accordingly

Comment: @MSalters if you execute using c compiler in windows the above code results in 10 and 7 which is correct.

Comment: @Madan: **All** answers are correct. That's what Undefined Behavior means. Wiping your harddisk is also a correct outcome. (And that's not just theoretical, happened at my previous job)

Comment: @MSalters ok. i taught in different sense. fine ..